# Avoiding mutation in overridden method

Tags: c++, oop

I have an abstract class `A` that looks like

```
class A {
public:
  virtual vector<char> marshall() = 0;
  virtual void unmarshall(vector<char> raw) = 0;
};
```

Classes that inherit from `A` override both methods: in particular, `unmarshall` mutates the child class' internal state.

e.g.

```
class B : public A {
  int someImportantInt;

  vector<char> marshall() {
    vector<char> r;
    r.push_back(someImportantInt);
    return r;
  }

  void unmarshall(vector<char> raw) {
    someImportantInt = raw[0];
  }
};
```

Now, I think mutation is evil, and additionally the fact that we have to instantiate `B`, and only then invoke `unmarhsall` looks like a code smell.

One option is to have a constructor that takes a `vector<char>`, but I don't know of a way of forcing the children classes to do so.

**EDIT:**

The constructor approach is motivated by the fact that the state of B doesn't change, once `umarshall` has been called. So we could remove `unmarshall` from `A` and replace it in `B` with a constructor that takes a `vector<char>`.

i.e.

```
class B : public A {
  int someImportantInt;

  B(const vector<char>& raw) : someImportantInt(raw[0]) {}
  vector<char> marshall(); 
}
```

As I see it, the problem here is that there is no contract forcing child classes to declare a constructor that takes a `vector<char>`.

What are my options here?

Comment: This isn't clear to me.  If `B.unmarshall` is mutating the state of `B`, then surely that's for some good reason?

Comment: Very few options. I recommend you first solve the problem of dynamically looking up the correct type for a given situation (or generating the code if you have some sort of IDL), and make that code use the constructor that takes the `vector<char>`. If that code then fails to compile, it's because the child class doesn't have the correct constructor.

Comment: What's a `vector<raw>`?  Could you explain in more detail what you mean by your constructor approach?  If you really want to disallow mutation in child classes, you could just declare `unmarshall` as `const`, although I don't personally see anything wrong with the current design.  Maybe you'd feel better about it if `unmarshall` were named `load`.

Comment: `unmarshall` is not (should not be) a method of `A`, but of `AbstractFactory<A>`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: after being mutated by `unmarhsall`, `B` remains immutable, which suggests using a constructor. This has its own shortcomings: please see the edit.

Comment: @n.m.: the abstract factory can only give me back objects of type `A`, but then I have no way of using specialized functional that's only present in the derived classes, no?

Comment: It should give you an `A*`.

Comment: Which I can only use to call methods in the abstract base class.

Comment: @abeln: Aha, I understand now.  `unmarshall` is effectively initialising the object.

Comment: If you are certain you have an marshalled `B`, you can use an `AbstractFactory<B>`. However if you always statically know types of your objects, it is not clear at all why inheritance and virtual functions are ever needed.

Comment: "One option is to have a constructor that takes a vector<char>, but I don't know of a way of forcing the children classes to do so." If you dont provide a default constructor or any other constructor child classes MUST pass a parameter to your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a template Marshaller class that does the marshalling and unmarshalling. Then use a data member of type Marshaller instead of just int in the class. Then in the constructor for Marshaller, you would initialize a vector member, so no class needs to know about it. Something like this:

```
template <class T>
class Marshaller {
  T real_data;
  vector<char> marshalled_data;
  Marshaller ();
  Marshaller (Marshaller&);
 public:
  Marshaller (T& t) :real_data(t) {
    // Do whatever with marshalled_data.
  }
  void marshall () {
    // Fill me in.
  }
  void unmarshall () {
    // Fill this in.
  }
  vector<char> rawData () {
    return marshalled_data;
  }
  bool isMarshalled () {
    return marshalled_data.size() > 0;
  }
  T& data () {
    return real_data;
  }
};

class B {
  Marshaller<int> someImportantInt;
 public:
  B () :someImportantInt(0) {}
  B (int i) :someImportantInt(i) {}
  int getImportantInt () {
    return someImportantInt.data();
  }
  vector<char> getRawInt () {
    return someImportantInt.raw data();
  }
  void unmarshall () {
    someImportantInt.unmarshall();
  }
};
```

I hope you understand the idea enough to give you a starting point. You might add more functions to Marshaller to take care of things like operator=() for when data is marshalled or not. I'm not sure where to go from this point since I'm not sure what you're wanting. This was my best guess, and you're free to modify it of course.